# NIntegrate: how to specify number of points (MaxRecursion is off by one)

Tags: numerical-integration

I was looking through the documentation for `NIntegrate` when I came across [an example that doesn't seem to make sense](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html#170212597).  Below is the code (with some minor adjustments relative to what's in the documentation) and the output.

```
TableForm[{Table[
Show[ListPlot[
  Last[Reap[
    NIntegrate[Exp[Cos[x]], {x, 0, 10}, 
     Method -> {"RiemannRule", "Type" -> t, "Points" -> 5}, 
     MaxRecursion -> 0, 
     EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, Exp[Cos[x]]}]]]], Filling -> 0, 
  PlotLabel -> t, PlotRange -> {{-1, 11}, {0, 3}}, Frame -> True, 
  Axes -> False, ImageSize -> Medium], 
 Plot[Exp[Cos[x]], {x, 0, 10}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Thin, Dashed}]], {t, {"Left", 
  "Right"}}]}] // Quiet
```

The part that I don't understand is that the number of points (`"Points"` in `Method`) is set to `5`, and `MaxRecursion` is `0`.  In this case, I'd expect `NIntegrate` to use only five points instead of `10`.  If `MaxRecursion` were set to `1`, I'd expect up to `10` points (i.e. a single recursive bisection).

I did the integration by hand to verify that `NIntegrate` is using twice as many points as I expected:

```
TableForm[Table[Flatten[{i, Table[
  NumberForm[
   NIntegrate[Exp[Cos[x]], {x, 0, 10},
    Method -> {"RiemannRule", "Type" -> t, "Points" -> 5},
    MaxRecursion -> i], 10],
  {t, {"Left", "Right"}}]}],
{i, 0, 1}],
TableHeadings -> {None, {"MaxRecursion", "Left", "Right"}}]
```

```
TableForm[
 Table[{n, 
  NumberForm[10/n*Sum[Exp[Cos[i*10./n]], {i, 0, n - 1}], 10], 
  NumberForm[10/n*Sum[Exp[Cos[i*10./n]], {i, 1, n}], 10]}, 
   {n, 5*Array[2^(# - 1) &, 3]}], 
  TableHeadings -> {None, {"n", "Left", "Right"}}]
```

(I had to put all output in one image because I can't post more than two links)
[image: output]
If I wanted to use only five (or three, seven, etc.) points to do the numerical integration, how would I do this with `NIntegrate`?  It seems to do at least one recursive bisection even if `MaxRecursion` is `0`.

```
 $Version  
 "11.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 28, 2016)"
```

Comment: It's because "Points" options in `NIntegrate` doesn't represent the total number of starting points. If you check `tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules` you will see it sometimes represent `2n - 1`, sometimes `2n + 1`. `"RiemannRule"` isn't documented there but it should be similar. Anyway this issue isn't very clear stated in the document and it's better to have a separate question for it. +1